# Angular handle event from the ng-template child in parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular app, I have a custom-list component, which takes in list of items. The component which is using it, uses custom-list-item component which has order buttons.

I need to handle the order change events in the custom-list-component, what is the best way to achieve this

The complete solution is hosted here...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uw1v8g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-list%2Fcustom-list.component.ts

Please suggest if I am approaching this generic list design incorrectly.

Comment: You can use custom events: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6zr6k?file=src/app/custom-list/custom-list.component.ts .

Comment: Thanks man, why don't you put that as an answer instead of a comment, so that it helps somebody looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple ways on how should we handle this scenario, but the one which comes to me is to use browser's Custom Event and handle them with Angular's `HostListener`

```
var event = new CustomEvent(
      'myCustomEvent',
      { payload: 'data'}
    );
```

and then dispatch it via

```
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

to handle it via angular's HostListener:

```
@HostListener('document:myCustomEvent', ['$event', '$event.detail.direction'])
  updateNodes(event, param1) {
    console.log(param1); //param 1 has $event.detail.direction value
  }
```

[Full Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6zr6k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-list%2Fcustom-list.component.ts)

[HostListener official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

[CustomEvent docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)